# Modify items in a list does not give any output

Tags: python, list, function

I'm finding really difficult modifying some items in a list.
I have a list comparable to a database, and I want to convert string values (which I would consider as missing values) to 99.

```
database = [2,5,11,33,78498,'abcqwe',13, 18,11,1993,'defrty']

def missing_values(i):
    for i in database:
        if type(i) == str:
            i = 99
    return 'Database cleaned'
```

When I run it, there are no syntax errors, even though "Database cleaned" does not appear. If I print(database), I see that nothing has actually changed. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

In the function, you are setting `i` to `99`, but never the value in your list. Where you set `i = 99`, you should first get the index of this value in your list, then set the value like this:

```
database[database.index(i)] = 99
```

You should also ensure you call the function as Abe said. There is also no need to pass a value through to this function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that you are calling your `missing_values()` function somewhere in your file otherwise the code will never be executed.

`missing_values()`

Also, seeing as you have defined the `database` variable in the same scope as `missing_values` you do not need the argument `i`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you don't see the list cleaned is because you don't return the list after cleaning, you instead just print a msg leaving the original list unchanged.

```
database = [2,5,11,33,78498,'abcqwe',13, 18,11,1993,'defrty']

def missing_values(i):
    for i in database:
        if type(database[i]) == str:
            database[i] = 99
    print 'Database cleaned'
    return database
```

Also you need to change the argument used in the function to from `i` to `database`. I assumed the `i` parameter is supposed to be the list that needs cleaning.

Answer (score 0):

You're not calling your function properly. Make sure then in somewhere of your code `missing_values()` it's been called.